# what is the difference between reading from a file to a location, then writing from that location to a file, and reading from a file directly to file

Tags: c, cs50, fwrite, fread

I was solving [volume (one of the questions in cs50x)](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/labs/4/volume/). Apparently the code that I wrote, works when the file contents are read in an array and from that array, written into the output file.

When I tried to read the input file contents to the output file, by giving a pointer to the output file, it didn't pop any error, but the output was not working.

Can someone explain how reading from a file to a location (say an array) and reading from one file into another file are different.

THIS IS THE CODE FOR REFERENCE

```c
`// Modifies the volume of an audio file

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Number of bytes in .wav header
const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check command-line arguments
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./volume input.wav output.wav factor\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open files and determine scaling factor
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    float factor = atof(argv[3]);

    // TODO: Copy header from input file to output file

    uint8_t arr[HEADER_SIZE];

    fread(arr, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);

    fwrite(arr, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, output);

    // creating a temprary location in memory for the content bytes of a wave file

    int16_t buffer;

    // TODO: Read samples from input file and write updated data to output file

    while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input))

    {

        buffer = (buffer) * factor;
        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
    }

    // Close files
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}`
```

But if I wrote the code below, it won't work

```c
   ` // TODO: Copy header from input file to output file

    // reading from the input file to the output file.

    fread(output, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);

    // creating a temprary location in memory for the content bytes of a wave file

    int16_t buffer;

    // TODO: Read samples from input file and write updated data to output file

    while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, input))

    {
        buffer = (buffer) * factor;
        fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(int16_t), 1, output);
    }`
```

Can someone explain how reading from a file to a location (say an array) and reading from one file into another file are different.

Comment: There is no way in C to directly "read from one file into another file".  Reads and writes are always from/to disk files, and to/from memory.  `fread` reads bytes from a disk file and copies them into memory.  `fwrite` takes bytes from memory and writes them to a disk file.  Depending on your needs, you can use different in-memory data structures: single variables, structures, arrays, etc.

Comment: it does not show any error, but the output audio file does not work (play any audio)

Comment: @SteveSummit Ah, but [sendfile()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) comes close to doing that - file data is copied directly and never reaches user space.  ;-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I was about to say, "OMFG, I had forgotten/repressed that!", but no, I don't have to, I left myself an out, I said there was no way *in C*. :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit True.  `sendfile()` isn't even POSIX.  AFAIK, it's just a Linux/Solaris extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186626/how-does-a-file-pointer-in-c-work) to understand what `FILE*` entails and why passing a pointer to a different type doesn't work as expected. More detail on the `FILE` structure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672746/what-exactly-is-the-file-keyword-in-c).

Answer (score 3):

In your second sample code you do a file read from `input` to `output`. In this specific case, `output` is considered as a `void *` buffer to store data ; not as a file handle to write data to.

```
fread(output, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);
```

You should rather consider something like this:

```
uint8_t buffer[HEADER_SIZE];
size_t read, written;

read = fread(buffer, 1, HEADER_SIZE, input);
written = fwrite(buffer, 1, read, output);
```

NOTE: for simplicity I do not check return values here, I leave it up to the OP.

EDIT:

1 - What is FILE pointer?

A `FILE *` is a pointer to a dynamically allocated `FILE` structure. This structure holds specific pieces of information used by the API to determine which file is concerned by read, write, seek, etc.

2 - Why doesn't writing to file handle works?

The `fread` function takes a pointer as first parameter. A `FILE *` is a pointer indeed. However, `fread` expects a memory region to write data to.

Passing a `FILE *` will be accepted by the compiler since every pointers cast okay to `void *`.

However, during runtime, the passed `FILE *` pointer will be used for storing read data bytes as a memory buffer. This means that `fread` will override the target memory structure with read content starting from the pointed address.

In the end, the `FILE *` structure will no longer hold the API data and thus, when the user will use the `FILE *` pointer for writing data to a file, the original  `FILE *` being corrupted, `fwrite` will most likely lead to a segfault.

Comment: The answer doesn't really explain anything concerning why the direct read/write operation using ```fread``` shouln't work. "In this specific case, output is considered as a void * buffer to store data ; not as a file handle to write data to.": so, what? Isn't the data written anyway to the output? Why no compiler or runtime error occurs? I think the answer would be much better if it explained what a FILE pointer actually is/does.

Comment: @picchiolu Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: `written = fwrite(buffer, 1, HEADER_SIZE, output)` probably should be `written = fwrite(buffer, 1, read, output)`, absent error checking.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Indeed !

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> The function fread() reads nmemb items of data, each size bytes
> long, from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at the
> location given by ptr.

Signature:

```
size_t fread(void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
                    FILE *restrict stream);
```

The first argument of `fread` is a void pointer that is to be written to. You passed it a `FILE *` in your code.

```
// reading from the input file to the output file.

fread(output, sizeof(uint8_t), HEADER_SIZE, input);
```

On a Unix-based system, you could map the file into memory with `mmap` and then work with it. Or just read the file into a buffer similar to how you did in your first example.

`FILE` is a structure defined in the standard library. It contains all the relevant information about the opened file.

From C11:

> (...) FILE which is an object type capable of recording all the
> information needed to control a stream, including its file position
> indicator, a pointer to its associated buffer (if any), an error
> indicator that records whether a read/write error has occurred, and an
> end-of-file indicator that records whether the end of the file has
> been reached; (...)

`fopen` returns a pointer to a `FILE` structure. The pointer itself is not pointing to the memory in the file, it's pointing to a structure of type `FILE`.

The contents of that structure are completely implementation defined.

Here's what `FILE` entails on my system:

```
type = struct _IO_FILE {
    int _flags;
    char *_IO_read_ptr;
    char *_IO_read_end;
    char *_IO_read_base;
    char *_IO_write_base;
    char *_IO_write_ptr;
    char *_IO_write_end;
    char *_IO_buf_base;
    char *_IO_buf_end;
    char *_IO_save_base;
    char *_IO_backup_base;
    char *_IO_save_end;
    struct _IO_marker *_markers;
    struct _IO_FILE *_chain;
    int _fileno;
    int _flags2;
    __off_t _old_offset;
    unsigned short _cur_column;
    signed char _vtable_offset;
    char _shortbuf[1];
    _IO_lock_t *_lock;
    __off64_t _offset;
    struct _IO_codecvt *_codecvt;
    struct _IO_wide_data *_wide_data;
    struct _IO_FILE *_freeres_list;
    void *_freeres_buf;
    size_t __pad5;
    int _mode;
    char _unused2[20];
} *
```

Comment: Why does the difference between FILE* and void* prevents the data from being written? Why no error raised?

Comment: these answers seem to be from robots.

Comment: There is no way in C to directly "read from one file into another file". Reads and writes are always from/to disk files, and to/from memory. `fread` reads bytes from a disk file and copies them into memory.`fwrite` takes bytes from memory and writes them to a disk file. Depending on your needs, you can use different in-memory data structures: single variables, structures, arrays, etc. –  Steve Summit
 I don't know how to pin the comments as this explains what I asked for

Comment: @SahilGautam I do not believe my answer was contrary to what he said. And yes, I'm a robot.

Comment: @picchiolu I edited my answer to include relevant information about a ```FILE``` pointer. I didn't find any information about what happens when you write data to it, and I do not feel like guessing. But perhaps, you could enlighten me?